# Meaning of "with" in "With four months until the November election" and "with the court sending the subpoenas back"

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

> With four months until the November election, the decisions may mean
> there will be no public revelations about Mr Trump’s financial affairs
> during an already difficult re-election battle.

I am not sure if the "with" here means at particular points.

> Save that, Both decisions pointed towards further litigation in the
> pair of the cases, with the court sending the subpoenas back to the
> lower courts for additional proceedings.

The “with” here means meanwhile something happens？

I failed to find an appropriate definition for it in these cases.
Source:  [Times US Supreme Court rules for handover of Trump tax returns](https://www.ft.com/content/2f249f8c-3aaa-4c41-bbe0-e78fd577b2ab)

Comment: The first "with" indicates an accompanying situation.  [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with) lists that sense under 7b -- a function word to indicate an attendant fact or circumstance.  The second "with" indicates an accompanying consequence.  This matches Webster's 7c -- a function word to indicate a result attendant on a specified action.

Answer (score 1):

It connects the first part of the sentence with the second part, implying that these two things are related. It connects "four months until the November election" with "the decisions may mean there will be no public revelations about Mr Trump’s financial affairs during an already difficult re-election battle."

You can think of it like "Since there are four months" or "Considering that there are four months".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found out more about it.